# Efficient way to parse html when only need first occurrence of specific tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a large html document. I am parsing it using BeautifulSoup, but the only information I wish to extract is the text of a specific tag (which I believe only occurs once).

Document is formatted like:

```
    <html>
        <div class=...>
            <div class=...
                <div class="foo">
    ...
    ...
```

Currently, I am using a SoupStrainer to filter for only div tags with the class "foo".
Perhaps I should be using a different library, or perhaps I misunderstand what SoupStrainer is doing.

```py
    html = open("file.html", encoding="UTF8").read()
    parse_only = SoupStrainer("div", class_="foo")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, "lxml", parse_only=parse_only)
    text = soup.text
```

I hoped this would be significantly faster than it was without the SoupStrainer, but I only got about a 2x speed-up and I would like it to be faster. I think that the reason for this is that it still has to check whether every single tag in the document matches  when straining it. I would like it to simply stop at the first tag that matches that and not spend time parsing any more of the document.

Comment: If your parsing task is so simple I would recommand not using a parsing package. Just use `string.find()`.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to use `lxml` library with `etree` hack.
That would be like reading tag by tag, not by reading the whole file. This is called Event Driven Parsing.

Please look here for more info https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#event-driven-parsing

and tutorial here:
http://boscoh.com/programming/reading-xml-serially.html
and here:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/

Those examples are for html, but you can use lxml for parsing html too.
I my case I had 1.1GB text xml file and looking throught whole file took me ~10m.

Quick example:

```
inputfile = open('file.html')
context = etree.iterparse(inputfile, events=('end',), tag='YOUR_TAG_NAME')

for event, elem in context:
    if event == END and elem.tag == 'YOUR_TAG_NAME':
        print(elem.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks suitable for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful Soup's [find](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) function should help you.

```
html = open("file.html", encoding="UTF8").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.find("div", class_="foo"))
```

This will fetch only the first match.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned- this was the first thing I tried. The problem is that the BeautifulSoup call parses the whole document, so is quite expensive.